# How to draw an overlay that matches the shape of an image with a transparent background using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image like this:

[image]

The image is transparent.  I want to apply a red overlay just on the letters of the logo.  I have experience with `cv2.addWeight(...)` but I always work on that using `cv2.rectangle(...)`.  Is there a way I can add a red overlay just on the shape of the image?

Comment: Do you mean you want all the visible letters to become solid red and the transparent parts to remain transparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alpha channel controls the transparent areas. So copying the alpha channel to the red channel should give a red overlay on the non-transparent areas. The `IMREAD_UNCHANGED` flag allows the reading of the signal without OpenCV removing the alpha (fourth channel).

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np;

img = cv2.imread('test.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
alpha = img[:,:,3];

imgz = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
imgz[:,:,2] = alpha;
imgz[:,:,3] = alpha;

dst = cv2.addWeighted(img, 0.7, imgz, 0.3, 0)

cv2.imwrite('test2.png', dst);

cv2.imshow("original", img)
cv2.imshow("alhpa", alpha)
cv2.imshow("final", dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Comment: And how would you reduce the opacity?

Comment: You mean make the parts outside the letters transparent again? That can be accomplished by copying the alpha channel to its place.

Comment: imgz[:,:,3] = alpha;

Comment: No I mean reduce the opacity of the red overlay?

Comment: How do you convert imgz to cv2?

Comment: Why do you have `imgz[:,:,2] = alpha` and `imgz[:,:,3] = alpha`?

Comment: Numpy arrays and opencv images are interchangeable according to my understanding as long as they have the same data type. 
That is why I used the dtype=np.uint8 is used.

Comment: The ```imgz[:,:,2] = alpha```. copies the alpha to red. And the imgz[:,:,3] = alpha copies the alpha to alpha. This makes the rest of the image transparent. When the two images are added together in addWeighted the result is still another transparent image except were the logo letters are.

Comment: I'm getting this error: `cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) /tmp/pip-req-build-99ib2vsi/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:691: error: (-5:Bad argument) When the input arrays in add/subtract/multiply/divide functions have different types, the output array type must be explicitly specified in function 'arithm_op'`

Comment: Probably because the ```dtype=np.uint8`` is missing in the call to ```np.zeros(img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)```

Comment: How can I use different colors?

Answer (score 3):

As you didn't answer my question in the comments, I am guessing what you want from the answer you have accepted.

You can do what you appear to want by simply adding a solid red overlay with weighting to the BGR channels only, without touching the alpha channel like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image including alpha channel
img = cv2.imread('google.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# Make a solid red overlay same height and width as original but without alpha channel
redOverlay = np.full_like(img[:,:,0:3], (0,0,255))

 # Add overlay to BGR channels leaving alpha unaffected and save result
img[..., 0:3] = cv2.addWeighted(img[..., 0:3], 0.7, redOverlay, 0.3, 0)
cv2.imwrite('result.png', img)
```

[image]

Comment: Mark, might this be a shorter alternate to replace your redOverlay using np.zeros.  Here I used np.full_like and then removed the alpha channel.   `redOverlay = np.full_like(img, (0,0,255,0))[:,:,0:3]` or remove the alpha channel first. `redOverlay = np.full_like(img[:,:,0:3], (0,0,255))`

Comment: @fmw42 That's much more gooder  thank you, Fred. I have edited it into the answer.